# Replace/Update entity and its children

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Lets say that i have 3 entities, `a`, `b` and `c`. Connected as `a <- b <- c`.

I make 2 instances of `a`; `a1` and `a2`. Both of them have some `b`:s and `c`:s connected to them.

What i would like to do is to replace `a1` wuth `a2`, including their children. In other words; removing a1 and its children, adding a2 + childrens on the same ID. Hope you get the idea, otherwise ill elaborate.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var tempB = a1.b;
var tempC = a1.c;

a1.b = a2.b;
a1.c = a2.c;

a2.b = tempB;
a2.c = tempC;
```

Or, perhaps:

```
var tempID = a1.ID;
a1.ID = a2.ID;
a2.ID = tempID;
```

---

I may have messed up with hierarchy; so:

```
var tempB = a1.b;

a1.b = a2.b;
a2.b = tempB;

// this copies c instances together with b instances
```

Comment: In your first example, you arent connection a1 to a2, just its childrens? And why cant you simply write `a1=a2`?

Comment: Q1: that's what I understood that you wanted. Q2: because that would make them perfectly equal.

Comment: You don't have to copy the c, its already connected to the b from a2

Comment: " replace a1 wuth a2, including their children. " so that icludes a1 and a2 as well. As for q2: since i want to do a replace of a1 to a2, thats pretty much what i want.

Comment: `var tempA; a1 = a2; a2 = tempA;`